# Can I change the value that's been entered in an input before the onChange is triggered using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, struts2, dojo

We use Dojo 1.9.3, and We have custom Widget that is essentially a wrapper that can contain any other Dojo widget as well as any Struts2 JSP component.

We currently have a problem with these components where trailing whitespace on both ends that's entered into a subcomponent is preserved when sending it to the server. This leads to bugs where a user may think the value is valid, but actually isn't.

We currently use the following code for handling onchange events (some code has been removed for brevity).

```
var containedWidgetId = this.containedWidgetId;
var containedWidget = registry.byId(this.containedWidgetId);
if (typeof containedWidget === "undefined") {
    containedWidget = dom.byId(this.containedWidgetId);
}

// get the Titlepane for later use.
var titlePane = registry.byId(this.containedWidgetId
                + "titleNodePane");

// Changes the Title and closes the TitlePane.
this.own(on(containedWidget, "change", function(e) {
    var newVal = "";
    // First check if the component value is stored as the displayed value.
    if (typeof containedWidget.attr == "function"
            && containedWidget.attr("displayedValue") !== null) {
        newVal = containedWidget.attr("displayedValue");
    }
    // if not, check if the onChange event is a Standard Dojo event.
    if (typeof e === "object") {
        newVal = containedWidget.value;
    } 
    var newTitle = this.prefixTitle + newVal;

    titlePane.set("title", newTitle);
    this.close();
    // tell the main page to do whatever is needed after the TitlePane is changed.
    this.onUpdate();
}.bind(this)));
```

Is there a way to tell Dojo "before this component (which can be both a Dojo component as well as a regular HTML compoment) triggers this onChange event, perform a `trim()` on the input"? Note that it needs to work on things other than Dojo inputs.

I've tried both aspect.before and aspect.around, but I can't seem to get the input argument when using either of them. As an example of aspect.before that doesn't work:

```
this.own(aspect.before(containedWidget, "onChange", function(e){
    if(typeof e === "string"){
        e = e.trim();                   
    }
    return [e];
}));
```

The code gets triggered before the onChange, but I can't seem to get the input value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this issue using a customer setter.

The setter (which must be defined with a special signature as dojo requirements) can detect a value, change that value (for example applying a trim) and make it available in the widget.

Example of custom setter dojo way:

```
_setFooAttr: function (value) {
     value = value.trim(); // do your trim here 
     this._set('foo', value);
 }
```

You can get your trimmed value back using:

`var value = this.get('foo');`

Interesting articles on custom getter and setter:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#quickstart-writingwidgets

https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/10/16/dojo-faq-what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-_set/

Comment: This doesn't help me, because it's not the value of the custom widget I created that's being set. The custom widget has a containedWidget which can be more than just a Dojo input widget. It can also be a HTML input or a Struts2 input. It's on this contained widget that I need do do preprocessing on the values that are entered, and I don't think I can change the _setValueAttr on elements that aren't Dojo components.